# .jar file doesn't open in Windows GUI but opens in Command Prompt Windows 8

Tags: java, jar

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4. When I build the project and execute the .jar file in dist folder made by IDE in Windows GUI environment, it shows waiting cursor for a moment and then nothing happens. But when I execute the same .jar file using Command Prompt CLI environment it executes the .jar successfully. The command I used to execute the file was:

```
java -jar D:\USB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EmbInterface\dist\EmbInterface.jar
```

Also, I have checked the default file association of .jar files. It's set to `C:\java....\javaw.exe`.

UPDATE: I tried to run it as administrator but when I right clicked the .jar file there was no such option.

Comment: did you try running as administrator?

Comment: @Saher your solution didn't i have updated my question...

Comment: Heeyyyyyy....is anybody there???????